# Android NDK build-host-executable.mk: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, adt

**Short question:**

I'm trying to build an app that has a JNI dependency, using Eclipse ADT and NDK r10e (the current version). The JNI dependency (apparently) builds a binary to run on the build host, using `build-host-executable.mk` from the NDK. However, that script seems to have been removed in recent NDK versions. What do I do?

**Long question:**

The JNI dependency is [platform/external/srec](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/srec/) from AOSP, which comes with an `Android.mk` file (actually, several of them).

I have set up Eclipse to build the native parts according to the instructions [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin), and copied the JNI code tree into the `jni` directory of my app's source tree. Additionally, I had to edit `jni/Android.mk`, adding the following line:

```
export TARGET_BUILD_TYPE := debug
```

which, as I understand it, would be set by the AOSP toolchain but is not set when building from Eclipse.

However, I get the following error:

```
android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-host-executable.mk: No such file or directory
```

This is caused by a line in one of my `Android.mk` files:

```
include $(BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE)
```

The NDK defines `BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE` in `build/core/build-all.mk`:

```
BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE     := $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/build-host-executable.mk
```

However, `build_host_executable.mk` is absent from the `build/core` directory (and so are the other `build-host-*.mk` scripts declared in the surrounding lines).

<del>Googling around a bit, I find that this script seems to have been present in earlier NDK versions (up to at least NDK <del>r7</del> r7b) but seems to be absent from later versions (possibly since r10b). The JNI lib was used by the (now abandoned) Voice Dial app. It had its last commit in December 2014, though the last real code change might have been in June 2014. AOSP had stopped building it by June 2015. Comparing this with the NDK release history, it might never have been built against NDK versions later than r9d or maybe r10.</del>

The NDK r7b I found appears to be a patched version to which host target support added, see also https://github.com/flyskywhy/android-ndk-host. Looks like support for this was planned in NDK and some stubs added, but it was never fully implemented. That gives me the choice of either building the host stuff with the local toolchain, or patching NDK r10e to add host target support.

On the other hand, this package has been part of AOSP for a while (Cyanogenmod included it until KitKat and dropped it in Lollipop), therefore the AOSP toolchain must have been capable of building it. Any pointers to that toolchain? Maybe it's possible to extract the relevant parts from the AOSP toolchain and add them to the package.

Comment: What happens if you drop the latest version of build-host-executable.mk into build/core?

Comment: Maybe try building the host executables without the NDK, i.e. with a standard make & gcc? Since they're not targeted to run on Android they can't really depend on the NDK... it should be possible to build them in isolation. That will require de-Androiding the makefiles though...

Comment: @ReubenScratton I have a link to r7b at https://github.com/flyskywhy/android-ndk-r7b, do you happen to know of any later versions? Google seems to offer only the current one...

Comment: @ReubenScratton I tried the file from r7b, changed `LOCAL_my` to `my` (as in r10e `build_executable.mk`). Now I get `Unknown LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS value: HOST_EXECUTABLE`, apparently the makefile has dependencies that got removed as well.

Comment: @ReubenScratton see my corrections to the question, apparently this feature was never part of NDK but the AOSP toolchain must have had it at some point...

Comment: Did you see this Q&A that relates to building one of the srec tools? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654810/building-just-one-tool-from-android-source-aosp   If I understand it right it's saying to do a full platform build and extract the srec host tools from that. Maybe the host-building stuff is in the ROM build scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/ must be where it's at, then...

Comment: Note that the answer also said that srec source has to be installed separately if building recent AOSP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JNI dependency in question is taken from the AOSP code tree. The toolchain used by AOSP is different from NDK, though both are built around a set of GNU make macros. The format for `Android.mk` (their makefile equivalent) is intentionally similar between both, so that in many cases a project can be built with either toolchain.

One case for which this will not work is host targets, i.e. building binaries (executables or libraries) intended to run on the build host rather than on the Android device. The AOSP toolchain has this kind of support but the NDK doesn't. Confusingly, the NDK does have some stubs for that functionality (including definitions for `BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE` and similar) but the implementation is missing.

There are three options. Be aware that the package you are building may depend on other packages from the AOSP source code, which you would need to build as well.

- Build the native code (or the host targets) using the AOSP toolchain, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30671099/2703209). This approach is most likely to be successful, as this is the toolchain for which the package was designed. It requires at least the packages containing the build tools, which are several gigabytes in size. You can get the entire AOSP source code as described [here](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), which should give you all the dependencies you need, but this will download some 50 gigabytes (!) of data.
- There is a patched version of NDK which adds support for host targets [here](https://github.com/flyskywhy/android-ndk-r7b) (or just the make macros [here](https://github.com/flyskywhy/android-ndk-host)). However, it is based on the now-outdated NDK r7b and had its last commit sometime in 2012 – you'll be working with a toolchain that is somewhat exotic and no longer maintained. Also, you'll need to determine your dependencies manually by examining the package.
- Ditch the `Android.mk` files that build the host targets and build these with a regular GNU toolchain. An introduction to that can be found [here](https://saidsecurity.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/how-to-compile-android-native-code-with-regular-makefile/). You can amend a higher-level `Android.mk` to invoke the "other" toolchain for your host targets, so you can automate the whole build. All of this may be a lot of work if the `Android.mk` content is very complex, but it is a one-time effort, after which your code will build with standard toolchains. As with the previous approach, you'll need to determine your dependencies manually. Dependencies which are required for the host target may be easier, though, if they are standard libraries which were ported to Android, as there may be an upstream version designed to be built with the GNU toolchain.

Comment: Can't  download 50GB of ASOP. Will the patched version work