# How to build Android's adb from source code?

Tags: android, adb, ndk-build, adbd

I'm trying to build Android's adb from source code, which I downloaded from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb).

I tried to use NDK21 and its `ndk-build`, but got this error

```
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-16.
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'adbd' in C:\Users\...\adb/jni/Android.mk.
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by C:\Users\...\adb/jni/Android.mk.
C:/Users/.../android-ndk-r21d-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r21d/build//../build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912804/how-to-build-host-static-library-with-android-ndk?noredirect=1&lq=1) question on stackoverflow with the similar problem, and tried to apply the answer from there. Downloaded the patched version of NDK7 from [here](https://github.com/flyskywhy/android-ndk-r7b) and tried to build adb with it, but still got a similar error

```
C:\Users\...\adb/jni/Android.mk:8: C:\Users\...\adb/jni/../platform_tools_tool_version.mk: No such file or directory
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'adb' in C:\Users\...\adb/jni/Android.mk.
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by C:\Users\...\adb/jni/Android.mk.
C:/Users/.../android-ndk-r7b-master/android-ndk-r7b-master/build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

All other solutions for `Trying to define local module ... this module was already defined` problem advise to change `Android.mk` file, but I have it from original source code, so I suppose it must be correct in the first place.

What else can I try to build adb?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned project is part of AOSP and should be built within AOSP build but it seems that it is already outdated because AOSP master is now using this one: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/adb/+/refs/heads/master