# How can I build ADB ARM myself?

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to build adb for ARM, but I couldn't find the adb folder in the platform_system_core repository at https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/tree/master. I've also tried cloning the official repository at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core, but the adb folder does not exist there either. Has the path changed? Can you tell me where to find the source code of adb and how to build it for ARM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build Android's adb from source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825490/how-to-build-androids-adb-from-source-code)

Comment: I found out adb path after cloning whole android, but when i build it it says have error

Comment: the error is `Aborted                 (core dumped) GOROOT=$(cd $GOROOT; pwd) ${mf_cmd} -b "${mf_bin}" -pkg-path "github.com/google/blueprint=${BLUEPRINTDIR}" -trimpath "${SRCDIR}" ${EXTRA_ARGS} -o "${built_bin}" $2` ,I forgot to say that